# Questions on while loop exercise

Tags: c++, while-loop

```
int main()
{
int number_of_words = 0;
int prevnum = -1;
string previous = "";
string current;
while (cin >> current)
{
    ++number_of_words;
    if (previous == current)
    {
        cout << "word number: " << number_of_words << "\n"
            << "Repeated Word: " << current << "\n";
        previous = current;
    }
    else while (prevnum == number_of_words)
    {
        number_of_words = 0;
        prevnum = 0;
        break;
    }
}
}
```

In this app, I'm trying to display repeated words and their position number within the text. When it finishes running the inputted statement, it keeps the `number_of_words` for the next input. I tried fixing this with the `else while` condition, at which the while loop would break.

What should I do differently?
Does the while loop run again after breaking or would i need to put this into another while loop that prompts the user on whether or not they are ready to type in some text?

*this is Ch. 3 so I'm guessing I should just move on but was curious

Comment: the question is not clear add the code which gives you trouble

Comment: because cout till after previous statement go to if condition .but when you don't put brackets previous is out of your if condition.right?

Comment: I don't understand the problem... In one case you execute always 'previous = current' (also if he if condition is not verified), otherwise not.

Comment: sorry, i tried making my problem more clear

Comment: I think you mean `else if` instead of  `else while`

Comment: But what is your goal ? Do you want count the numer of words in a single input, right ? For examples, you type "aa bb bb cc cc dd", do you want print that there are 2 repetitions that are "bb" and "cc" ?

Comment: Yup, that is the goal. Now when I send in "aa bb bb cc cc dd", the read out should be something close to:  "word number: 3 Repeated word: bb". The program continues to wait for input so I can put in "aa bb bb cc cc dd" again but now the readout is: "word number : 9 Repeated word: bb". I'm not sure how to make it so that the word number resets to 0.

Comment: You execute `previous = current;` only when you know that they're already equal. That seems to be meaningless. Rather you would want to execute this when you know they're different.

Comment: How does your program handle this case: "aa bb cc bb cc dd"?  There are repeated words, but they are not the same as the previous word.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int number_of_words;
    string previous;
    string current, input;

    while (true)
    {
        previous = "";
        number_of_words = 0;
        cout << "\nWrite the data\n";
        getline(std::cin, input);
        stringstream ss;
        ss << input; 
        while (ss >> current)
        {
            ++number_of_words;
            if (previous == current)
                cout << "word number: " << number_of_words << "\n"
                    << "Repeated Word: " << current << "\n";
            previous = current;
        }
    }
}
```

I have used an stringstream variable to break every loop of input, so i could reset the counters.